# SetBinding using string path only fires change event on SetBinding in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, .net-4.0

I am not sure if this is a bug in `4.0` or a misunderstanding of DP's and bindings on my part.
*Note: this works in 3.5 and 4.5...just not 4.0

Consider the following code:

VM:

```
public MyEnum MyProp
{
    get{return _myProp;}
    set
    {
        _myProp = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProp");
    }
}
```

View(Dependency Property setup):

```
 MyDP= DependencyProperty.Register("MyProp", typeof(MyEnum), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(DefaultEnumVal, MyPropChanged));
```

View(in the datacontextchanged event):

**First Option**

```
this.SetBinding(MyDP, "MyProp"); //Only triggers MyPropChanged once
```

**Second Option**

```
this.SetBinding(MyDP, 
    new Binding
    {
        Source=this.DataContext, 
        Path = new PropertyPath("MyProp")
    }
); //Works as expected
```

So, given all of that, why does the first option only trigger the property changed once, and the more verbose method continues beyond the first change? I thought that the first/string version inherently used the `this.DataContext`? If I install `.NET 4.5`, then this works as expected for both, which leads me to believe that this is a 4.0 bug, possibly related to doing this in the `DataContextChanged` event?

But, maybe I am missing something, so that is why I am asking here :)

UPDATE

[Even per Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> By default, bindings inherit the data context specified by the
>   DataContext property, if one has been set

And, per reflection:

```
public BindingExpression SetBinding(DependencyProperty dp, string path)
{
    return (BindingExpression)this.SetBinding(dp, new Binding(path));
}
```

So, all this does is call the same code as above, just without setting the source. This should result in the update working against the `DataContext`

I am able to reproduce the first option if I leave the `Source` `null` in the second option

UPDATE #2

Apparently in 4.5, they added a `ResolvedSource` property. This shows that in 4.5, the source resolves to what I expect. I traced that to the `ClrWorker` and found that the `SourceItem` is indeed being evaluated correctly...at least at the time of `SetBinding`. I am going to see if there is a way for me to keep track of this to see if/when it changes.

UPDATE #3

After further debugging, I found that the changed event only occurs on the `SetBinding`. If I set the `DefaultEnumValue` to be what it is when the `SetBinding` occurs, then the change does not trigger at all

UPDATE #4

If I call `this.SetValue(MyDP, SomeEnumVal);`* then this works and even writes into the VM. I have tried changing the DP so that the metadata is set to be twowaybindingbydefault to see if that helps, but it did not

*This does not surprise me since SetBinding itself does a `target.SetValue(dp, bindingExpressionBase);`, which explains why it works one time.

Comment: Use `Snoop` to inspect the bindings in both cases to see the difference. BTW, unless this is some complex custom control (such as a custom `DataGrid`, what you're doing is completely not recommended.

Comment: You mean setting the binding in the code behind? This was originally created by a co-worker and I planned on asking why this was not done in the XAML. Even still, these should be equivalent

Comment: Not only that. What type of properties are these? again, usage of custom `DependencyProperties` only make sense if this is a custom control.

Comment: This is a custom control, so the custom DP actually does make sense here

Comment: so just to confirm, the datacontext of your control is your view model?

Comment: Correct, ala `this.DataContext` in the second example

Comment: How is `MyPropChanged` defined?

Comment: It is just a method that sets the ContextMenu differently depending on the enum

Answer (score 0):

It certainly seems odd, but I *think* what's happening here is not related to the Binding's Source, but how you're setting the Path. Your first case calls `SetBinding(DependencyProperty, string)`, which in turn calls `SetBinding(DependencyProperty, new Binding(path))`. The `Binding` constructor internally sets the `Path` to be `new PropertyPath(path, new object[0])` - a path with no parameters.

In the second case, you're creating your own `PropertyPath`, but via a different constructor that takes a single argument of type `object`, which represents a parameter. That constructor seems to set `Path` to be `"(0)"` and sets your `"MyProp"` string as a parameter to the binding.

Here's what MSDN says about that constructor:

> This constructor has two completely different usages depending on
>   whether it is being used for a source-mode property path for a
>   binding, or for a target-mode single-step property path for a
>   storyboard target.
>
> If using this PropertyPath in source mode for a binding, parameter is
>   a string representing a property name, or can be a string that
>   describes a "step-through" path to the property in the CLR object
>   model of the object that is being used as the source for a binding.
>   For a binding property path, the character that identifies a "step" is
>   a dot (.). Indexer references (including multiple indexers, and type
>   differentiation) are also supported. For more details on the syntax of
>   the string as specifically used by the Binding object, see
>   Binding.Path. A property used as a binding source need not be a
>   dependency property. If the binding updates two-way, the property
>   referenced must be read-write. Also note that the binding target does
>   have to be a dependency property. For details, see Data Binding
>   Overview.
>
> If using this PropertyPath in target mode for a single-step path for a
>   storyboard target, parameter is generally provided as type
>   DependencyProperty. You can also specify a string that is the Name.
>   Either of these evaluate to the same result, because it is stored
>   internally as a string. A provided DependencyProperty is converted to
>   a string through DependencyPropertyConverter. The
>   DependencyPropertyConverter supports a qualified naming format for
>   dependency properties, so you can specify a typeName.propertyName
>   qualified dependency property name string to the
>   PropertyPath.PropertyPath constructor in code. The qualified path to
>   the dependency property identifier is a different concept than a
>   complex path. A complex-path PropertyPath should instead be created
>   with the PropertyPath.PropertyPath constructor.

I'm still not sure why your first case doesn't work, but imagine that for some reason, since the parameter doesn't *have* to be a dependency property but can be a regular CLR property, its being treated as the latter.

In the second case, the property is being interpreted as a "single-step path for a storyboard target" (even though I imagine its probably not), but since in this usage it *must* be a dependency property, the binding handles it differently.

For consistency, you could try in your second case to set Path as:

```
Path = new PropertyPath("MyProp", new object[0])
```

Of course, now I would expect your binding to only work once in both cases! It might restore some sanity, but could also indicate that the binding problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't the issue. You might want to read all of my updates on my own digging if you havent already. I have gone down a bunch of different paths and still end up nowhere